# List the cheapest 1-n hours every day in Month with R

Tags: r, group-by

I'm trying to create a function that searches and calculates the desired number of cheapest hours. The data is the history of electricity prices with hourly accuracy.

There are two variables in my df:

```
DateTime, POSIXct yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm
Price, numeric
```

I manage to find the two smallest or largest values in the entire material. But for each day, the search was unsuccessful. Would you be able to help.

```
> cheapest_2_hours <- function(data){
+     sorted_data <- data %>% 
+         group_by(DateTime) %>% 
+         summarise(Cheapest_Price = min(Price)) %>% 
+         arrange(Cheapest_Price) %>% 
+         top_n(2)
+     return(sorted_data)
+ }

> cheapest_2_hours(df)
Selecting by Cheapest_Price

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  DateTime            Cheapest_Hinta #in fact these are two highest values
  <dttm>                       <dbl>
1 2022-08-08 09:00:00           107.
2 2022-08-08 19:00:00           107.
```

What I wanted

```
1 2022-08-08 09:00:00           107.
2 2022-08-08 19:00:00           107.
3 2022-08-08 05:00:00           10.2
4 2022-08-08 13:00:00           4.7
.
.
```

Whole period.

Comment: In your function, once the data are summarized, they are no longer grouped.  So, `top_n(2)` will return the two smallest values, which is what you got.  If you want the data to be grouped and then return the smallest values, you will have to group your data again after `summarise()`.

Comment: I think you want to first group by day and hour, use `summarise` to pick the cheapest price, then only group by day and use `top_n(2)`. It's hard to suggest code without a reproducible example to work with.